# how to display multiple values in select tag?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I want to display some name in the select tag but I am not able to do that.I have setter and getter  of type string:

```
public void setFinalApprover(String finalApprover) {
        this.finalApprover = finalApprover;
    }
```

I am fetching data from database in the methodin DTOService Class like:

```
public List addApprover(EmpRegistrationForm leaveApplyForm){

            List list=new ArrayList();
            try {
                con=DBConnection.getConnection();
                String Approver="select emp_name from newemp_register where userType='employee'";
                PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement(Approver);
                ResultSet rs=pstmt.executeQuery();

                if(rs.next())
                {

                    leaveApplyForm.setFirstApprover(rs.getString(1));
                    list.add(leaveApplyForm);

                }               

            } catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }   

            return list;

        }
```

My controller class is like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registerForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public ModelAndView showForm(@ModelAttribute("registerForm")EmpRegistrationForm EmpRegistrationForm, BindingResult result , ModelMap model,EmpRegistrationForm empRegistrationForm , HttpServletRequest request) 
       {
         log.info("Inside Controller returning to loginform page....");
         CommonDTOBean dtoBean=new CommonDTOBean();

        EmpRegistrationForm registerForm =  new EmpRegistrationForm();
        model.put("registerForm", registerForm);    

        model.remove(registerForm);
        EmpRegisterWorker worker=new EmpRegisterWorker();
        List status=worker.addApprover(EmpRegistrationForm);

        if(status!=null){
            model.put("status", status);

        }
}
```

and I am display values from list on jsp page like:

```
<tr><td><spring:message code="label.firstApprover"> </spring:message></td>
    <td><form:select path="firstApprover" name="firstApprover">
<form:option  value="">${status.firstApprover}</form:option>
```

now the problem here is,It is displaying only one value however resultset is returing multiple values.Please help me to solve this.

Is there any way to pass multiple values from DTOSerive class to controller and from controller back to jsp page?And for

```
String Approver="select emp_name from newemp_register where userType='employee'";if(rs.next())
                {

                    leaveApplyForm.setFirstApprover(rs.getString(1));
                    list.add(leaveApplyForm);

                }      getting error like wrriting aborted to setFirstApprover.
```

Comment: You need to use <form:options items="${status.firstApprover}" />

Comment: I have tried that but did not work.

Comment: I am a bit confused - you are having problem with displaying options list or having a multiselect?

Comment: I think problem is with having multiselect.

Comment: what exact error you getting post it, and you not using spring properly, why you creating `new EmpRegisterWorker();` in GET? creating objects task handover to spring it will manage well it desgined for that, and use spring `JdbcTemplate` for database access.

Answer (score 0):

Your Select tag should look like this. This should work.

```
<forms:select path="firstApprover" items="${status}" />
```

The content you want your select tag should filled up is referred using `status` property set in `ModelMap`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="firstApprover" >
<c:forEach items="${status}" var="stat">
     <option value="${stat.your value}"> 
             ${country.your value}
     </option> 
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

In **Select option tag value** you can set your actual expected data with **stat** variable.

i.e. append your key with stat like my model key is name so i just append it like **stat.name**.